# Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

```
// Other variables
$MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 260;
$file_name = $_FILES[$upload_name]['name'];
//echo "testing-".$file_name."<br>";
//$file_name = strtolower($file_name);
$file_extension = end(explode('.', $file_name)); //ERROR ON THIS LINE
$uploadErrors = array(
    0=>'There is no error, the file uploaded with success',
    1=>'The uploaded file exceeds the upload max filesize allowed.',
    2=>'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form',
    3=>'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
    4=>'No file was uploaded',
    6=>'Missing a temporary folder'
);
```

Any ideas? After 2 days still stuck.

Comment: A better explanation for the reason https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/08/28/php-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference/

Comment: Warning about this: as of PHP 7.4 (perhaps earlier versions, too), assigning a variable inline as a function argument/parameter which is passed by reference results in this notice-level error.
E.g. https://onlinephp.io/c/4c871

Answer (score 657, accepted):

Assign the result of `explode` to a variable and pass that variable to `end`:

```
$tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_extension = end($tmp);
```

The problem is, that `end` requires a reference, because it modifies the internal representation of the array (i.e. it makes the *current element pointer* point to the last element).

The result of `explode('.', $file_name)` cannot be turned into a reference. This is a restriction in the PHP language, that probably exists for simplicity reasons.

Comment: @Oswald, We can turn the warning off using `error_reporting`. Is it safe to do so?

Comment: It is safe to turn off `error_reporting`. It is not safe to blindly ignore errors. Turning off `error_reporting` is a major step towards blindly ignoring errors. In the production environment, turn off `display_errors` instead, and write errors to a log file.

Comment: Not working.
The answer below - double parenthesis - works.

Comment: How to turn off these notices however? I tried ignoring E_NOTICE but they still show up

Comment: Every day I hate PHP a little more... :-(

Answer (score 67):

Everyone else has already given you the reason you're getting an error, but here's the best way to do what you want to do:
`$file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: I agree. There's no point in using string manipulation to parse file paths when you have appropriate APIs to do so.

Comment: this is the best answer for me, the string manipulations just add little mess in the code

Answer (score 59):

Php 7 compatible proper usage:

```
$fileName      = 'long.file.name.jpg';
$tmp           = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileExtension = end($tmp);

echo $fileExtension;
// jpg
```

Comment: Weird. That works but how? Does it suppress the warning, similar to what the `@` prefix does?

Comment: @NigelAlderton No it does not suppress errors like `@` does. Try `$test = end((explode('.', array('Error!'))));` [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ed64996b6456710ba03e6af60d5b8d658eec76c)

Comment: So why does adding an extra parenthesis remove the error?

Comment: I researched this quirk and it seems to be a **bug?** with the **php parser** where **double parenthesis** "(())" causes the reference to be converted to a plain value. More on this [link](http://phpsadness.com/sad/51).

Comment: I like this .. but I don't like it at the same time.  Thanks for ruining my day :-)

Comment: In php7 warning will be still issued.
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.parentheses

Comment: So, it works because it's a bug you should not suggest it, no?

Answer (score 31):

save the array from explode() to a variable, and then call end() on this variable:

```
$tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_extension = end($tmp);
```

btw: I use this code to get the file extension:

```
$ext = substr( strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1);
```

where `strrchr` extracts the string after the last `.` and `substr` cuts off the `.`

Answer (score 24):

The answer given elsewhere,

```
$tmp = explode('.', $fileName);
$file_extension = end($tmp);
```

is correct and valid. It accomplishes what you are trying to do.

#### Why?

The `end()` function does not do quite what you think it does. This is related to how the PHP `array` data structure works. You don't normally see it, but arrays in PHP contain a pointer to a *current element,* which is used for iteration (like with `foreach`).

In order to use `end()`, you must have an actual array, which has attached to it (normally, invisibly), the current element pointer. The `end()` function physically modifies that pointer.

The output of `explode()` is not an actual array. It is a function output. Therefore, you cannot run `end(explode())` because you violate language requirements.

Simply setting the output of `explode()` in a variable *creates the array* that you're looking for. That created array has a current element pointer. Now, all is once again right in the world.

#### So what about the parentheses?

This is not a bug. Once again, it's a language requirement.

The extra parentheses (like `end((explode()))`) do more than just grouping. They create an inline instance variable, just like setting the function output to a variable. You may think of it as a lambda function that is executed immediately.

This is another correct and valid solution. It is perhaps a better solution, as it takes less space. A good reviewer or maintainer should grok what you're trying to do when they see the extra parentheses.

If you use a linter or SCA program like PHPCS, that may dislike the extra parentheses, depending on the linting profile you're using. It's your linter, tell it what you want it to do for you.

Some other answers also list things like the spread operator or `array_key_last()`, which are also reasonable solutions. They may be perfectly valid but they're more complicated to use and read.

#### I'll just use the `@` prefix

This solution is valid, however incorrect. It is valid because it solves the problem. That's about the end of its merit.

**Suppressing errors is always bad practice.** There are many reasons why. One very large one is that you are trying to suppress *one specific* error condition (one that you have created), but the error suppression prefix suppresses *all* errors.

In this case, you will probably get away with this. However, engaging in bad programming habits is cheating and will likely lead you to cheat more and bigger in the future. You will be responsible for bad code. But I'm not the Code Police and it's your code. It's valid because it solves the problem.

#### Okay, so what's the best answer?

Do what [@ryeguy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636215/5583468). Don't do string manipulation to solve a well-defined problem that the platform already solves for you. Use `pathinfo()`.

This has the added benefit that it actually does what you want, which is finding the extension on a file name. There is a subtle difference.

What you are doing is getting *the text following the final dot.* This is different from finding the file extension. Consider the file name, `.gitignore`. PHP knows how to handle this. Does your code?

Once again, I'm not the Code Police. Do what suits you best.

Comment: `end((explode()))` is still giving the notice; not sure if this changed in recent PHP versions

Answer (score 13):

Since it raise a flag for over 10 years, but works just fine and return the expected value, a little [stfu operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) is the goodiest bad practice you are all looking for:

```
$file_extension = @end(explode('.', $file_name));
```

But warning, don't use in loops due to a performance hit.
Newest version of php 7.3+ offer the method `array_key_last()` and `array_key_first()`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php

```
                 uuuuuuu
             uu$$$$$$$$$$$uu
          uu$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$uu
         u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
        u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
       u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
       u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
       u$$$$$$"   "$$$"   "$$$$$$u
       "$$$$"      u$u       $$$$"
        $$$u       u$u       u$$$
        $$$u      u$$$u      u$$$
         "$$$$uu$$$   $$$uu$$$$"
          "$$$$$$$"   "$$$$$$$"
            u$$$$$$$u$$$$$$$u
             u$"$"$"$"$"$"$u
  uuu        $$u$ $ $ $ $u$$       uuu
 u$$$$        $$$$$u$u$u$$$       u$$$$
  $$$$$uu      "$$$$$$$$$"     uu$$$$$$
u$$$$$$$$$$$uu    """""    uuuu$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$"""$$$$$$$$$$uuu   uu$$$$$$$$$"""$$$"
 """      ""$$$$$$$$$$$uu ""$"""
           uuuu ""$$$$$$$$$$uuu
  u$$$uuu$$$$$$$$$uu ""$$$$$$$$$$$uuu$$$
  $$$$$$$$$$""""           ""$$$$$$$$$$$"
   "$$$$$"                      ""$$$$""
     $$$"                         $$$$"
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$parts = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_extension = end($parts);
```

The reason is that the argument for `end` is passed by reference, since `end` modifies the array by advancing its internal pointer to the final element. If you're not passing a variable in, there's nothing for a reference to point to.

See [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) in the PHP manual for more info.

Answer (score 10):

`end(...[explode('.', $file_name)])` has worked since PHP 5.6. This is documented in the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking#by-reference_passing) although not in PHP docs themselves.

Comment: I like this one line solution.

Comment: this is clever – using extra brackets does not suppress the notice, but the spread conversion does.

Answer (score 9):

PHP complains because `end()` expects a reference to something that it wants to change (which can be a variable only). You however pass the result of `explode()` directly to `end()` without saving it to a variable first. At the moment when `explode()` returns your value, it exists only in memory and no variable points to it. You cannot create a reference to something (or to something unknown in the memory), that does not exists.

Or in other words: PHP does not know, if the value you give him is the direct value or just a pointer to the value (a pointer is also a variable (integer), which stores the offset of the memory, where the actual value resides). So PHP expects here a pointer (reference) always.

But since this is still just a notice (not even deprecated) in PHP 7, you can savely ignore notices and use the ignore-operator instead of completely deactivating error reporting for notices:

```
$file_extension = @end(explode('.', $file_name));
```

Comment: @OskarCalvo That's also my philosophy. But this is not an error - PHP treats it as a "notice". And it was an alternative "solution" to other answers here, which no one directly mentioned it. A better way would be to save the value of `explode` to a temporary variable, like others wrote here. But again: This is not an error, so it is ok to use this operator. PHP is generally bad at error handling. Therefore I would suggest to use `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler` for error handling and as cleanest solution.

Comment: It's a horrible answer. An error could be everywhere - for example, $file_name could be unsuitable for explode or doesn't exist. But @ will suppress them all.

Comment: I'm not down voting this since it's algo a valid answer, but it's certainly a very bad advice. You may get mad to debug later if something occurs there...

Comment: @YourCommonSense You may not like the advice given and I agree. But the answer explains the _origin_ of the message, which is too often missing in SO answers. When I understand what's going on, I can make up my mind about the advice. I would not want to use the `@` myself, but I think the answer is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Just as you can't index the array immediately, you can't call end on it either.  Assign it to a variable first, then call end.

```
$basenameAndExtension = explode('.', $file_name);
$ext = end($basenameAndExtension);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP offical Manual :
end()

Parameters

```
array
```

The array. This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

Comment: Make a quote from official manual, don't rewrite by your own hands. Also, consider to make your answer better than existing one.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to store the value in a variable like this

```
$value = explode("/", $string);
```

Then you can use the end function to get the last index from an array like this

```
echo end($value);
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

assume:

```
function endSimulator (&$var) {
    echo $var;
}
function explodeSimulator ($var) {
    return $var;
}
```

now, in controadictory with `explodeSimulator` which can get "functions output" you can feed `endSimulator` just by variables
otherwise php says "only variables should be passed by reference"
you can check this with below code:

```
  endSimulator(explodeSimulator(":)")); // warnings arise
```

why?
because when php reachs "& symbol", he looks for a "pointer to sth (a variable in general terms)" after it, any variable is a "pointer" (to a perimitive or reference-see additional information) but functions can be evaluate to values not pointers! (although i think in javascript they point to a variable whith the same name of corresponding function)
in another words, when you use `endSimulator(explodeSimulator(":)"))`, interpreter see something like `endSimulator(":)")`, as you know you can not send ":)" to a function which is just feeded with pointers
so finally you can solve this like:

```
  $explodeSimulatorOutput = explodeSimulator(":)");
  endSimulator($explodeSimulatorOutput);
```

**additional information**

i think many peaple here have an ambiguius mind about the phrase "pass by reference", please note that "passed by reference" is a general idea and can be used in vast various of situations like:

```
a=10   // a <-- 10; 
// content of a is passed by a value into it

b="a" // b <-- "a";
// content of b is passed by a value into it

obj = {a,b} // obj <-- {} <-- 10,"a";
// content of obj is passed by a reference (which is {}) into it

function func1 (var) {...}
// the "var" variable is passing by value

function func2 (&var) {...}
// the "var" variable is passing by reference into the function
```

"passing by reference" in this topic refers to the concept of `func2` not `a`, `b` or `obj`