# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference - php error

Tags: php, variables, standards, strict

```
    $file_name = $_FILES['profile_image']['name'];
    $file_ext = end(explode('.', $file_name)); //line 10
    $file_ext = strtolower($file_ext);
    $file_temp = $_FILES['profile_image']['tmp_name'];
```

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in on line 10

How do I get rid of this error? Please and thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4636166/1255289)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`end()` expects its parameter to be able to be passed by reference, and only variables can be passed by reference:

```
$array = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_ext = end( $array);
```

You can fix this by saving the array to a variable first, then calling `end()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last item in the array, do this:

```
$arr = explode(".", $file_name);
$file_ext = $arr[count($arr) - 1];
```

If you're trying to just get the extension from the file, use

```
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you write $ext = end(explode('.', $filename)); for getting the file extension then "Only variables should be passed by reference" can be show in php. For this reason, try to use it two steps, like:
$tmp = explode('.', $filename);
$ext = end($tmp);