# Explode string on the last occurrence of character

Tags: php, explode

I am using `php 7.4` and I have the following string:

```
Tester Test Street 11 (Nursing Home, Example), 1120 New York
                                             '-------------Split String here 
                                   '-----------------------NOT HERE
```

When I do `explode()` I get:

```
$addressAll = explode(", ", "Tester Test Street 11 (Nursing Home, Example), 1120 New York");

/*
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string "Tester Test Street 11 (Nursing Home"
  [1]=>
  string "Example)"
  [2]=>
  string "1120 New York"
}
*/
```

However, I would like to get:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string "Tester Test Street 11 (Nursing Home, Example)"
  [1]=>
  string "1120 New York"
}
```

Any suggestions how to only split the last occurrence of `,`.

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explode only by last delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610791/explode-only-by-last-delimiter)

Comment: If `explode()` does not do what you need then don't use `explode()`. Or use it and process the value it returns to achieve your goal, don't expect it to do what it was not designed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strrpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the position of the last comma in the input string and [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to extract the substrings located after befora and after the last comma:

```php
$input = 'Tester Test Street 11 (Nursing Home, Example), 1120 New York';
$pos = strrpos($input, ',');
$prefix = substr($input, 0, $pos);
$suffix = substr($input, $pos + 1);
```

See it [in action](https://3v4l.org/vvtDn).

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php).
The string is separated by a single comma, which is only followed by characters without a comma up to the end of the character string.

```
$input = 'Tester Test Street 11 (Nursing Home, Example), 1120 New York';

$array = preg_split('~,(?=[^,]+$)~',$input);
```

?= causes the expression in brackets not to be used as a back reference.