# how to store selective data in variable got from user? and show him whole result [PHP]

Tags: php, facebook, image, view

i want a simple php code that will get data from user e.g( https :// fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/c0.0.180.180/s160x160/1525356_685076001544625_985694702_a.jpg)
i want just this code from user from above example (1525356_685076001544625_985694702_a.jpg)
when he will put all code into my website then my website will show him his/her large image.

-Note:i just want selective part(1525356_685076001544625_985694702_a.jpg) from user
and show whole result like this - https : // fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/1525356_685076001544625_985694702_n.jpg

any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Seems to work fine. I just tested with a profile picture. If you can edit your code into the question, or open another question, I am sure you will get help!

Comment: no man you are really nice please can u make php code whole as it is for me??
bcz i'm newbie sorry
action=done.php
please make complete done.php for me? plz?

Comment: I'm unsure what `done.php` is for. You already show the fullscreen picture on `profil.php`, what else is there to do?

Comment: here it is mine link which is being created by me:
http://itxjanu.tk/pic/

Comment: You have to change form action to `http://itxjanu.tk/pic/done.php`.

Comment: OMG!! its working fine now
but it does not showing my pic there
it gives me link:https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/1525356_685076001544625_985694702_n.jpg
i want that user will get his/her image there not a link

Comment: Place `<img>` tags around the image. `echo '<img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/' . $code . 'n.jpg">';`

Comment: last thing mate
when i use $input = $_POST['resimbaglanti'];
it does not show me anythng

Comment: Use `$input = $_POST['url']`, because that is what your input is named.

Comment: i want to get user's data not a fix url :/

Comment: It's not a fixed url, in your HTML, your input textfield is named `url`. Please try it and see if that works for you. If you mean getting the user's data from a facebook login button, that's a whole question on using facebook API and creating a facebook application.

Comment: thank u man <3
no issue :)
be my frnd please your personal email please?
i will not tease u :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$input = 'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/c0.0.180.180/s160x160/1525356_685076001544625_985694702_a.jpg';

$code = explode('/', $input);
$code = $code[sizeof($code)-1];

$code = substr($code, 0, -5);

echo 'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/' . $code . 'n.jpg';
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/q9G5UBua):

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/1525356_685076001544625_985694702_n.jpg
```

Comment: thank u so much for helping me i'm gonna test it
can u tell me one more thing?
that is i need $input = (user's data not selective link you have just posted above)
have a look please on this:
http://www.profileviewer.comoj.com/

Comment: The name for the input is `resimbaglanti`. Try `$input = $_POST['resimbaglanti'];`.

Comment: let me try plz hold on
thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Dave Chen anwser (shorter).

```
 $input = 'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/c0.0.180.180/s160x160/1525356_685076001544625_985694702_a.jpg';  

 $code = explode('/', $input);
 $code = substr(end($code), 0, -4);

 // or   version < PHP 5.4 
 $code = substr(end(explode('/', $input)), 0, -4);


 echo 'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/' . $code . 'n.jpg';
```

Comment: shorter code is looking nice :)

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636166/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference). Depending on your PHP version or on what errors/warning you may have enabled, this may be an issue. http://php.net/end

Comment: @DaveChen did you see that site i gave u above?

Comment: @Dave Chen thanks! I forgot

Comment: Of course. It looks amazing, good job on it!

Comment: kindly tell me your personal email address thank you where i can talk to you frendly

Comment: i dosenot work for me bcz i want it in website version
so please help..

Comment: @Dave Chen fixed. And change '-5' to '-4' in your code.Its mistake.

Comment: I think it's `-5`. The file is being changed from `a.jpg` to `n.jpg`, the string's length is five.

Comment: @Dave Chen http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php