# Ambigous PHP error message

Tags: php

Having this:

```
...
private $responseBuffer = array();
...
```

and within this line:

```
$lm = end(array_values($this->responseBuffer));
```

I get

`Error: Only variables should be passed by reference (2048)`

as both `end` and `array_values` are built in and do not have a `call-by-reference`I'm puzzled, any one an idea?

(purpose: get the latest value out of `$responseBuffer`)

Comment: You need a variable - `$foo = array_values($this->responseBuffer); $lm = end($foo);`, `end`'s first arg is by ref

Comment: @Clive oops, i didn't see you answered already..

Comment: I didn't @xurshid29, keep yours there ;)

Comment: Here's an explanation as to why you need to assign `array_values` to a variable before passing to `end` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4636183/1426354

Answer (score 5):

[end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function receives the arguement by reference, do like this:

```
$var = array_values($this->responseBuffer);
$lm = end($var);
```

Comment: Yepp, thanks, just read the manual, as always RTFM ...