# PHP error - Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, strict

I have error in my php file ->
"Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /page/editor/manager/trlib.php on line 57"

```
function TR_fileExt($filename)
 {
  return strtolower(end(explode('.', $filename))); //// line 57
 }
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: `$tmp = explode('.', $filename); return strtolower(end($tmp));` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4636183/689579 for reason.

Comment: and you might be interested in http://docs.php.net/pathinfo