# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in please

Tags: php

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in please

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","docx","pdf");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors="<div align='center'><font color='red'>extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.</font></div>";
  }
```

Comment: You should replace this `explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']))` with a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636166/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `end` expects an array passed by reference. So the passed array has to be a variable.

```
  $var = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
  $file_ext=strtolower(end($var));
```

[This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php#refsect1-function.end-parameters)