# Only variables should be passed by reference in error?

Tags: php, phpmailer

i am getting this when try to send email via php mailer any buddy can help it out 
here is the code which i use

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }

    if($file_size > 2097152) {
        $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }

    if(empty($errors)==true) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: please show exact error message including line number

Comment: @Jeff Ran this through my server as a test, I'm presuming this is the error he's getting:

`PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference in E:\sierr\Documents\Sync\sync\code\snippets-php\tmp.php on line 16`

Which references this line:

`$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4636166/1255289)

Answer (score 7):

The issue is in this line:

```
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
```

The `end()` function's parameter is passed 'by reference', meaning the function directly modifies the variable that is passed into the function. Because of this, you can't pass a function directly into `end()` - You have to store the output of `explode()` into a variable first, then pass that variable into `end()`. Some relevant documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

This change to the above line should work:

```
    $file_name_array = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
    $file_ext=strtolower(end($file_name_array));
```

Answer (score 2):

`end` is a function which **moves the internal array pointer** to the end of the array. It does so by taking an array reference and modifying its array pointer. This line will emit a warning:

```
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
```

The reason it does that is because `explode` is a function which will return an array. PHP is just telling you that you're trying to move the array pointer but aren't keeping track of the array you're moving the pointer of.

However as a side effect `end` also returns the element at the end (which is what you want I'm assuming). Splitting into two lines will work:

```
 $array = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
 $file_ext=strtolower(end($array)); // Now a variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

see this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636183

Assign the result of explode to a variable and pass that variable to end:

```php
$tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_extension = end($tmp);
```

The problem is, that end requires a reference, because it modifies the internal representation of the array (i.e. it makes the current element pointer point to the last element).

The result of `explode('.', $file_name)` cannot be turned into a reference. This is a restriction in the PHP language, that probably exists for simplicity reasons.