# PHP Error Was encountered, and I can not debug it myself

Tags: php, debugging, syntax-error

I am struggling to debug a PHP error I am getting when uploading photos to my website. It is not WordPress btw. The error message says
"A PHP Error was encountered, Severity: Notice
Message: Only variables should be passed by reference
Filename: admin/vehicles.php
Line Number: 322"

Below is the line of text from that file and line 322. I'm not sure if this is enough info to go off of, but if it's a simple syntax error, I'm sure it is.

```
 $ext = array_pop(explode('.', $_FILES['slider_image']['name']));
```

Thanks in advance! I can provide more of the code if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636166/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171076/php-why-should-only-variables-be-passed-by-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_pop` expects an actual variable, not a returned array, because it works with a pointer.

Try this:

```
$array = explode('.', $_FILES['slider_image']['name']);
$ext = array_pop($array);
```

Just to expand a bit on that:

If you use `explode('.', $_FILES['slider_image']['name']);`, you get an array. However, this array doesn't really exist. Its basically homeless. When you assign it to a variable, it gets an actual "address" in the memory.

`array_pop` only accepts references, not values (this is known as "pass by reference" vs "pass by value"). So you don't give `array_pop` a value, but the address to the value. These functions usually have a `&` sign in front of the variable name in the function definition.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php