# Dynamic Breadcrumbs not seeing nested folders

Tags: php, dynamic, breadcrumbs

I used the code found [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594624/1941676) for dynamic php breadcrumbs for my website. It works great! however, If I nest a folder more than 1 deep, It causes errors.

Here's the code that I have currently for the breadcrumbs.

```
    <?php
    function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
        $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
        $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
        $breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");
        $last = end(array_keys($path));
        foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
            $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));
            if ($x != $last)
                $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";
            else
                $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
        }
        return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
     }
    ?>
    You are here: <?= breadcrumbs(' ♥ ') ?>
```

The easiest place to see a live example is [*here*](http://jmariemayer.zzl.org/pixel_art/contests/my_awards.php). If you click on the third link on the breadcrumbs, it ignores the second nested folder. I don't know enough PHP to trouble shoot the problem and how to fix it. I would think ideally it would watch for nested folders in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add previous crumbs to get it working correctly. Here's a fix:

```
<?php
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
    $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
    $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");
    $last = end(array_keys($path));
    foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));
        if ($x != $last)
            $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";
        else
            $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
        $base .= $crumb . '/';
    }
    return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
 }
?>
You are here: <?= breadcrumbs(' ♥ ') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you're just linking to the current "crumb" `$base$crumb`

for you'll need to keep track of the path while building the links

```
foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
            $base .= $crumb.'/';   // <- keep adding crumbs to current path
            $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));
            if ($x != $last)
                $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base\">$title</a>";  //<- link to current path
            else
                $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your script runs fine , I see you have `open_basedir restriction in effect` so you would have to ,if you're on apache to add this to your httpd.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs>
 php_admin_value open_basedir none
 </Directory>
```

If script causes problems try one of the answers already given