# PHP Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, html, breadcrumbs

I'm creating a dynamic breadcrumb menu, it's grabbing the url and outputting each directory to the end user correctly but for example if you click the first breadcrumb link after home, it's still using the FULL url and also adding 'array to the end too'. I'll post the code below to make some send of this and screenshots.

PHP/HTML

```
<?php 
    $crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
}
?>

<div class="breadcrumb">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php HTTP_HOST ?>">Home</a></li>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $crumb){ ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $crumbs; ?>"><?php echo $crumb; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How it appears so far:

[image]

---

The link which it tried to load when I clicked In-House-Training for an example.

[image]

Comment: you need to assign something like this - `ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');` to a variable...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594211/php-simple-dynamic-breadcrumb 

Try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're generating your URL wrong. Notice how you're echoing `$crumbs` array into `a` href attribute. You should start your url with your site root url and on every foreach loop pass, add appropriate piece of string

```
$url = "http://www.yoursite.com";

<div class="breadcrumb">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $url ?>">Home</a></li>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
          $url .= "/".$crumb;
        ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $crumb; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```