# How to link my links on my breadcrumbs?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'd like to know how I can link all my links on my two breadcrumbs (top and bottom) so that I can know where I am on my site? I would like for example when I go to my page rules.php, "Rules" is displayed on my breadcrumbs: http://prntscr.com/48anw3

Here is my structure:

index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "index") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Forums</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "members") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Members</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "sign_up") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Sign Up</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "sign_in") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Sign In</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "change_theme") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Change Theme</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "contact_us") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Contact Us</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "help") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Help</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "rules") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Rules</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("top_bar.php");?>
        <?php include("header.php");?>
        <?php include("container.php");?>
        <?php include("footer.php");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

top_bar.php file:

```
<!-- TOP BAR -->
<div id="top_bar">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="top_bar_links">
            <ul>
            <?php
            $full_name = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
            $name_array = explode("/",$full_name);
            $count = count($name_array);
            $page_name = $name_array[$count-1];
            ?>
            <li>
                <a id="home" href="../">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="forums" class="<?php echo ($page_name=="index.php")?"active":"";?>" href=".">Forums</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="members" class="<?php echo ($page_name=="members.php")?"active":"";?>" href="members">Members</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

header.php file:

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 id="logo">
            <a href=".">Test</a>
        </h1>
        <div id="member_links">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a id="sign_up" href="sign_up">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="sign_in" href="sign_in">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

container.php file (where my breadcrumbs are placed):

```
<!-- CONTAINER -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="breadcrumb_top">
            <div class="breadcrumb_links">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "index") !== false) { ?>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Forums</h1>
        <h3 id="category_title">Categories</h3>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "members") !== false) { ?>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Members</h1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "sign_up") !== false) { ?>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 15px;">Sign Up</h1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "sign_in") !== false) { ?>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 15px;">Sign In</h1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "change_theme") !== false) { ?>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Change Theme</h1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "contact_us") !== false) { ?>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Contact Us</h1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "help") !== false) { ?>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Help</h1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "rules") !== false) { ?>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Rules</h1>
        <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eu nibh turpis. Nunc sit amet auctor elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In malesuada lobortis tempus. Integer auctor condimentum sapien, non scelerisque eros cursus et. In vel leo elementum, iaculis tellus sit amet, vestibulum quam. Etiam dapibus pulvinar risus, vestibulum rhoncus sapien commodo vitae. Etiam sit amet ultrices dui. Suspendisse luctus fringilla eros. Nam vitae metus porttitor, sagittis arcu eleifend, malesuada odio. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Pellentesque id velit a elit porttitor sollicitudin et vulputate nisl. Donec eu purus non libero porta malesuada et non lorem. Vestibulum ultrices vitae elit vitae accumsan. Quisque euismod, quam sed ornare ultrices, magna mi posuere massa, vel placerat ipsum est quis erat. Aliquam non libero mauris. Etiam ligula velit, commodo et feugiat ac, porta eu orci. Donec laoreet ipsum in urna auctor, vitae malesuada nibh consequat. Donec sit amet libero vitae erat rhoncus venenatis. Maecenas nec pretium justo, eget fermentum tellus. Ut aliquet tellus venenatis posuere fermentum. Fusce mattis velit et tellus suscipit consectetur.</p>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="breadcrumb_bottom">
            <div class="breadcrumb_links">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

My sitehttp://nextgenfocus.com/

Thanks to the people who will take the penalty to read the question and help me.

Comment: You would like something like home > rules ? is there any limits? for example can I have home > rules > forums > rules ??

Comment: I do not want "Home". I just want that when for example I click on "Members" in the navigation, "Members" is also displayed in the breadcrumbs.

Comment: I do get that, but my question is if you have levels or something of the kind so you don't repeat on the breadcrumb eternally

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some simple solutions for Breadcrumbs,

This option if you are using htacces is a great chooice

```
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    echo ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
}
```

Taken from:
[PHP Simple dynamic breadcrumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594211/php-simple-dynamic-breadcrumb)

If you need something more specific would gladly help out :)

Some other chooices:
http://www.phpro.org/classes/Breadcrumbs.html

http://pixelcode.co.uk/tutorials/php/breadcrumbscript-using-php/

------UPATE-------
This should do the trick

```
<?php
if($location = substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1))
    $dirlist = explode('/', $location);
else
    $dirlist = array();

$count = array_push($dirlist, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

$address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

echo '<a href="'.$address.'">Home</a>';

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    echo '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;<a href="'.($address .= '/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.ucfirst(str_replace(".php","",$dirlist[$i])).'</a>';
?>
```