# How to explode URL and set "a" tag to every word(s) between "/"?

Tags: php, replace, explode, strtr

For example, if URL is `http://localhost/category/news/old-stuff` then this function gives me this result:

```
<a>newsold stuff</a>
```

**Question:**

how to put every word(s) between `/` to `<a>` tag ?

*Example:*

`<a>news</a>`
`<a>old stuff</a>`

**Function i am using:**

```
$address =  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$current = strtr($address, array('localhost' => '', 'category' => '', '/' => '', '-' => ' ' ));
echo '<a href="#">'. $current .'</a>';
```

Thanks for any answers and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Simple dynamic breadcrumb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594211/php-simple-dynamic-breadcrumb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$ex = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
foreach($ex as $val){
    echo '<a>'.str_replace('-',' ',$val).'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$url =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$tags = explode('/', $url);
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo "<a href='#'>" . str_replace('-',' ',$tag) . "</a> ";
}
```