# PHP Breadcrumb Generates Empty Link

Tags: php

I'm using this simple code to generate breadcrumbs:

```
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
<?php
  $crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    echo '   <li>';
    echo '<a href="'.$crumb.'">';
    echo ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . '');
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<span class="divider">/</span></li>' . PHP_EOL;
   }
?>
  </ul>
```

Right now my URL is `http://example.com/gallery.php`.

For some reason this script is generating an empty anchor tag and an anchor tag for `gallery.php`.

Could anyone tell me why an empty anchor tag is being generated?

The actual output is:

```
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
   <li><a href=""></a><span class="divider">/</span></li>
   <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a><span class="divider">/</span></li>
  </ul>
```

I got this example from: [PHP Simple dynamic breadcrumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594211/php-simple-dynamic-breadcrumb)

Comment: Because `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` starts with a `/` so you always get a minimum of two array elements when exploding. Try this: `explode("/", trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `explode("/", "/asd/ddd")` returns `["", "asd", "ddd"]`

Add an if statement will work.

```
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    if(!$crumb) continue;
    echo '   <li>';
    echo '<a href="'.$crumb.'">';
    echo ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . '');
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<span class="divider">/</span></li>' . PHP_EOL;
   }
```